# SQL - Select the playlist with the most movies

Tags: sql, database, hsqldb

I am struggeling with a query.

I have two tables:

```
CREATE TABLE Playlist(
    id INTEGER GENERATED BY DEFAULT AS IDENTITY PRIMARY KEY,
    name VARCHAR(255) NOT NULL,
);



CREATE TABLE PlaylistMovies(
    mid INTEGER FOREIGN KEY REFERENCES Movie(movieid) ON DELETE CASCADE,
    pid INTEGER FOREIGN KEY REFERENCES Playlist(id) ON DELETE CASCADE,   
    PRIMARY KEY (mid, pid)
);
```

I want to find the playlist with the most movies(counted mid`s).

How to approach this problem?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this out please:

- [SQLFIDDLE DEMO](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/f94f9/3)

Query:

```
select top 1 pl.pid, p.name,
         count(pl.mid) as count_id
  from playlistmovies pl
  left join playlist p
  on p.id = pl.pid
  group by pl.pid, p.name
  order by count_id desc
;
```

Results:

```
| PID | NAME | COUNT_ID |
-------------------------
|   1 |   p1 |        5 |
```

Comment: @maximus the question is if you have two playlists with same max count of movies...what do you want to return?

Comment: Just one id? well think about it... P1 has 4 movies in it, P2 has 4 movies in it, and max count is 4. Do you just want P1 or both? To me returning both P1, P2 makes sense :) if you choose P1 then P2 could say *hey I too have a max count...* :D